# Proving an inequality which leads to the proof of irrationality of $ \frac{1}{e}$

Tags: inequality, irrational-numbers

I was trying to prove that $\ln\left(2\right)$ is irrational, but accidentally I ended up with the proof of irrationality of $\frac{1}{e}$.

Here is a proof of mine which has been inspired by the famous proof about irrationality of $e$ Which has been done by  Joseph Fourier.

> **Proof**:

It's known that :

$$1-\frac{1}{e}=\sum_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$
using this  it can be shown that:

$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{\left(-1\right)^{0}}{1!}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{1}}{2!}<\frac{\left(-1\right)^{0}}{1!}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{1}}{2!}+...<\frac{\left(-1\right)^{0}}{\left(10\right)^{0}}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{1}}{\left(10\right)^{1}}+...=\frac{10}{11}<1$$
Now assume $1-\frac{1}{e}$ is rational,in other words: 
$1-\frac{1}{e} =\frac{a}{b}$, where $a,b∈ℤ^+$ , also $b≠1$, because then $\frac{1}{2}<1-\frac{1}{e}=\frac{a}{b}=a<1$, which is a contradiction since $a∈ℤ^+$.
Define:

$$x:=b!(1-\frac{1}{e}- \sum_{n=0}^{b}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!})$$

Plug the substitution $1-\frac{1}{e}=\frac{a}{b}$,
$$x=b!( \frac{a}{b}- \sum_{n=0}^{b}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!})=a(b-1)!- \sum_{n=0}^{b}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

Since $\sum_{n=0}^{b}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}∈ℤ$ and $ a(b-1)!∈ℤ$ implies $x∈ℤ$.

Rewrite $x$ such that:

$$x=b!( \sum_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!}- \sum_{n=0}^{b}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!})=\sum_{n=b+1}^{∞}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

Also $b$ is either odd or even, W.L.O.G let $b$ to be an odd number,then
Since $b$ is odd then the lower limit of the sum starts with an even number,in other words:

$$\frac{b!}{(n+1)!}- \frac{b!}{(n+2)!}>0 ⇔(n+2)!>(n+1)!$$

Hence $$x=\sum_{n=b+1}^{∞}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}>0$$

There are two cases to consider:

**I)**

where $n=2k$ for some $k∈ℤ$
with this assumption for all terms with $n ≥ b + 1$ we have the upper estimate:

$$\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}=\frac{1}{\left(b+1\right)\cdot\cdot\cdot\left(b+\left(n-b+1\right)\right)}<\frac{1}{\left(b+1\right)^{\left(n-b+1\right)}}$$

implies:
$$\sum_{n=b+1}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}<\sum_{n=b+1}^{∞}\frac{1}{\left(b+1\right)^{\left(n-b+1\right)}}$$

Changing the index of summation to $n-b↦k$ we have the following relation:

$$\sum_{n=b+1}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}<\sum_{k=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{\left(b+1\right)^{\left(k+1\right)}}=\frac{1}{\left(b+1\right)^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{b+1}}\right)=\frac{1}{b\left(b+1\right)}<\frac{1}{2}$$

now consider the following case:

**II)**

where $n=2k+1$ for some $k∈ℤ$
with this assumption for all terms with $n ≥ b + 2$ we have the upper estimate:

$$\frac{-\left(b!\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}=\frac{-1}{\left(b+2\right)\cdot\cdot\cdot\left(b+\left(n-b+1\right)\right)}<0$$

implies:

$$\sum_{n=b+2}^{∞}\frac{-\left(b!\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}<0$$

Using **I** and **II** , we conclude:

$$x=\sum\limits_{\substack{ {n=b+1}  \\ \\  {n \enspace\text{even}}    }}^\infty \frac{\left(b!\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!} +\sum\limits_{\substack{ {n=b+2}  \\ \\  {n \enspace\text{odd}}}}^\infty \frac{-(b!)}{\left(n+1\right)!}<\frac{1}{2}$$
Finally it has been shown that $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$ , which is clearly a contradiction since $x∈ℤ$, implies

$$\boxed {1-\frac{1}{e}\ne\frac{a}{b}⇔1-\frac{1}{e}∈ℚ^{c}}\tag{1}$$
for all $b$ odd.

Now we have the same strategy for $b$ , when it's an even number:

Since $b$ is even then the lower limit of the sum starts with an odd number,in other words:
$$\frac{-(b!)}{(n+1)!}+ \frac{b!}{(n+2)!}<0 ⇔(n+2)!>(n+1)!$$

Hence $$x=\sum_{n=b+1}^{∞}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}<0$$

There are two cases to consider:

**III)**

where $n=2k+1$ for some $k∈ℤ$
with this assumption for all terms with $n ≥ b + 1$ we have the upper estimate:

$$\frac{-1}{\left(b+1\right)^{\left(n-b+1\right)}}<\frac{-1}{\left(b+1\right)\cdot\cdot\cdot\left(b+\left(n-b+1\right)\right)}=\frac{-(b!)}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

implies:
$$\sum_{n=b+1}^{∞}\frac{-1}{\left(b+1\right)^{\left(n-b+1\right)}}<\sum_{n=b+1}^{∞}\frac{-(b!)}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

Changing the index of summation to $n-b↦k$ we can have the following relation:

$$\frac{-1}{2}<\frac{-1}{b\left(b+1\right)}=\frac{-1}{\left(b+1\right)^{2}}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{b+1}}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{∞}\frac{-1}{\left(b+1\right)^{\left(k+1\right)}}<\sum_{n=b+1}^{∞}\frac{-(b!)}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

now consider the following case:

**IV)**

where $n=2k$ for some $k∈ℤ$
with this assumption for all terms with $n ≥ b + 2$ we have the upper estimate:

$$0<\frac{1}{\left(b+1\right)\cdot\cdot\cdot\left(b+\left(n-b+1\right)\right)}$$

implies:

$$0<\sum_{n=b+2}^{∞}\frac{\left(b!\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

Using **III** and **IV** , we conclude:

$$\frac{-1}{2}<x=\sum\limits_{\substack{ {n=b+1}  \\  {n \enspace\text{odd}}    }}^\infty \frac{-(b!)}{\left(n+1\right)!} +\sum\limits_{\substack{ {n=b+2}  \\  {n \enspace\text{even}} }}^\infty \frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

Finally it has been shown that $\frac{-1}{2}<x<0$ , which is clearly a contradiction since $x∈ℤ$, implies

$$\boxed {1-\frac{1}{e}\ne\frac{a}{b}⇔1-\frac{1}{e}∈ℚ^{c}}\tag{2}$$
for all $b$ even.

From ${(1)}$ and ${(2)}$, it easily can be concluded that for neither $b$ odd nor $b$ even :
$$\color{green} {\boxed {1-\frac{1}{e}\ne\frac{a}{b}⇔1-\frac{1}{e}∈ℚ^{c}}}$$

It's well-known that the sum of a rational and an irrational number is irrational , since $1$ is rational and $1-\frac{1}{e}$ is irrational , implies $-\frac{1}{e}$ is irratioal, the same can be said for $\frac{1}{e}. \qquad\blacksquare   $

Also an upper and lower bound of $\frac{1}{e}$ can be concluded easily using the first inequality:
$$0<\frac{\left(-1\right)^{2}}{2!}+...+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}}{\left(n+1\right)!}+...<\frac{1}{2} $$

The question is  : How it can be shown that 
$$\frac{\left(-1\right)^{0}}{1!}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{1}}{2!}+...+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!}+...<\frac{\left(-1\right)^{0}}{\left(10\right)^{0}}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{1}}{\left(10\right)^{1}}+...=\frac{10}{11}<1$$

I know the inequality is true just because I know the value of $1-\frac{1}{e}$, but I want a proof which does not use this fact.

Updated:
now I know my answer about the inequality but can someone determine whether my proof is right or it is not.

Comment: Nit-pick: "Taylor series of $1-\frac{1}{e}$ around $x=2$" doesn't really mean what you want it to mean. That Taylor series is given by $(1-\frac1e)+0(x-2)+0(x-2)^2+\cdots$.

Comment: @Arthur,I edited,is that clear now?

Comment: I'm not nit-picking the exact phrasing. I'm nit-picking the fact that you can't, in any meaningful way, Taylor expand a constant. You can Taylor expand a _function_, and then insert a value afterwards. Such as the function $1-e^x$ around $x = 0$, and inserting $x = -1$. But I don't actually think you need to justify it at all. The series $1-\frac1e = \sum\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)!}$ is already known to most who would read your proof. And someone who doesn't know this and also can't tell immediately that it is true, probably won't be able to judge / correct your proof anyways.

Comment: @Arthur,I agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is **not** valid, but it can be easily fixed.

The following part has an error :

> Define:$$x:=b!(1-\frac{1}{e}- \sum_{n=0}^{b}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!})$$Plug the substitution $1-\frac{1}{e}=\frac{a}{b}$,
>   $$x=b!( \frac{a}{b}- \sum_{n=0}^{b}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!})=a(b-1)!- \sum_{n=0}^{b}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$Since $\sum_{n=0}^{b}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}∈ℤ$ and $ a(b-1)!∈ℤ$ implies $x∈ℤ$.

Note that $\sum_{n=0}^{b}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}$ is not an integer since the last term of the sum is $\frac{(-1)^n}{b+1}$ which is not an integer.

---

The following is a proof which is based on your idea.

Basically, all you need is to change the definition of $x$.

Let us define $x$ as follows :

$$x:=b!\bigg(1-\frac{1}{e}- \sum_{n=0}^{\color{red}{b-1}}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!}\bigg)$$Then, supposing that $1-\frac{1}{e}=\frac{a}{b}$, we get
$$x=a(b-1)!- \sum_{n=0}^{b-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}\quad (∈ℤ)$$

which can be written as

$$x=b!\bigg( \sum_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!}- \sum_{n=0}^{b-1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!}\bigg)=\sum_{n=b}^{∞}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$
$$=\sum_{\substack{ {n=b}  \\  {n \enspace\text{even}}    }}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}-\sum_{\substack{ {n=b}  \\  {n \enspace\text{odd}}    }}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}$$

**Case 1** : If $b$ is odd, then $x$ is negative.

Since 
$$\frac{b!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{(b+1)(b+2)\cdots (n+1)}\lt\frac{1}{(b+1)^{n-b+1}}\tag1$$
we get
$$\sum_{\substack{ {n=b}  \\  {n \enspace\text{odd}}    }}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}<\sum_{m=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{\left(b+1\right)^{2m-1}}=\frac{b+1}{(b+1)^2-1}\lt\frac 12$$
We also have
$$\sum_{\substack{ {n=b}  \\  {n \enspace\text{even}}    }}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}\gt 0$$
So, we get
$$x=\sum_{\substack{ {n=b}  \\  {n \enspace\text{even}}    }}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}-\sum_{\substack{ {n=b}  \\  {n \enspace\text{odd}}    }}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}\gt -\frac 12$$
from which we have $-\frac 12\lt x\lt 0$, which contradicts that $x$ is an integer.

**Case 2** : If $b$ is even, $x$ is positive.

From $(1)$, we get
$$\sum_{\substack{ {n=b}  \\  {n \enspace\text{even}}    }}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}<\sum_{m=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{\left(b+1\right)^{2m-1}}=\frac{b+1}{(b+1)^2-1}\lt\frac 12$$
We also have
$$\sum_{\substack{ {n=b}  \\  {n \enspace\text{odd}}    }}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}\gt 0$$
So, we get
$$x=\sum_{\substack{ {n=b}  \\  {n \enspace\text{even}}    }}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}-\sum_{\substack{ {n=b}  \\  {n \enspace\text{odd}}    }}^{∞}\frac{b!}{\left(n+1\right)!}\lt \frac 12$$
from which we have $0\lt x\lt \frac 12$, which contradicts that $x$ is an integer.

Comment: so the only problem caused the error is that $b$ which should be $b-1$?

Comment: @Absurd: Yes! To check if there are other errors, I wrote the above proof which is based on your idea. Then, I found no other errors.

Answer (score 1):

Because $$\frac{\left(-1\right)^{0}}{1!}+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{1}}{2!}+...+\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!}+... $$ is  an [alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), whose terms decrease in absolute value monotonically to zero,

it converges to a value less than that of the first term (which is $1$)

or the sum of the first three terms (which is $1-\frac12+\frac16=\frac23<\frac{10}{11}<1$).

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: How do you determine what does the whole alternating series converges to is less than $10/11$?, I just know the sum of the two consecutive partial sum exept the first term (which is $1$) is a negative value which clearly says the alternating series is always less than $1$ ,but does not determine that the alternating series is also less than $10/11$, I just cannot understand how we can show the value which the alternating series converges to is less than what the right hand side series converges to.(which is $10/11$).

Comment: The alternating series converges to less than $\frac23$ (sum of first three terms), which is less than $\frac{10}{11}$

Comment: So I think we can say $\sum_{n=0}^{∞}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\left(n+1\right)!}<\frac{2}{3}<\frac{10}{11}<1$, and it holds because $\frac{-1}{\left(n+1\right)!}+\frac{1}{\left(n+2\right)!}<0\ \left(n\ge1\right)$, in other words:
$1+\underbrace{\frac{-1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}}_\text{<0}+\underbrace{\frac{-1}{\left(n+1\right)!}+\frac{1}{\left(n+2\right)!}}_\text{<0}=\underbrace{1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}}_\text{= 2/3}+\underbrace{...-\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!}+\frac{1}{\left(n+2\right)!}-...}_\text{<0}<\frac{2}{3}<\frac{10}{11}<1$

Answer (score 0):

Let me present my own proof of irrationality of $\,e\,$ or $\,e^{-1}\,$ or even $\,e^r\,$ for arbitrary rational $\,r\ne 0.\,$ I believe that my proof is original (let me know if you saw it in **print** or on the **Internet**).

For the above, it's enough to prove the irrationality of $\,e^{\frac {-1}q}\,$ for arbitrary positive integer $\,q.$

Given an arbitrary positive integer q, the arbitrary rational number $\,f\,$ is of the form

$$ f\,=\,f_{F\,n\,q}\,\,=\,\frac F{n!\cdot q^n} $$

where also $\,n\,$ is a positive integer, and $\,F\in\Bbb Z.$    ***Indeed***, let
$\, f:=\frac ab,\,$ where $\,a\,b\in\Bbb Z\,$ and
$\,b>0.\ $ Then,

$$ f\,=\,f_{a\cdot(b-1)!\cdot q^b\,\,  b\,\,q}\,
=\,\,\frac{a\cdot(b-1)!\cdot q^b}{b!\cdot q^b} $$
***Great!***

On the other hand
$$ e^{\frac{-1}q}\,=\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty
      \frac{(-1)^n}{n!\cdot q^n}\,=\,\,
   \lim_{n=\infty}\frac{E_n}{n!\cdot q^n} $$

where $\,E_n\,$ is the numerator of the $n$-th partial sum of the given series; and looking at the
remainders of the above alternating series we
know that
  $$ 0\, <\,\left|\frac{E_n}{n!\cdot q^n} -
 e^{\frac{-1}q}\right|\,<\,\frac 1{n!\cdot q^n} $$

In the light of above, $\,e^{\frac{-1}q}\,$ is not a rational number.   ***GREAT!***

> All you need to know was about the remainders of the exponential series -- the classical stuff. And nothing more, there was **no** additional computation.

Comment: @Absurd, thank you, I'll fix it.

Comment: In all proofs about rational numbers that I know of, one always reduces the fractions. Above, I UNreduce the fractions!

Comment: @Absurd, only a small percentage of mathematicians are willing and able to follow unnecessarily involved proofs -- call them mathematical *hackers*. The majority of mathematicians have a hard time to follow any proof. When it is **worth it** then indeed they force themselves to absorb even difficult (but reasonably well written) proofs. I feel, that before I can judge the whole of your proof I need you to work on it to make it intellectually more attractive. I see your true but unjustified 4th line $\,(\frac 12=\ldots<\frac{10}{11})\,$ and I cannot force myself to go on. Try to clean your prf.