# Why is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(b+1)^k}=\frac{1}{b}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, geometric-series, geometric-progressions

I was looking through in stack math and got this answer: [Prove that $e$ is irrational](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/713472/631742) by [Yiorgos S. Smyrlis](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/57021/). (This answer is copied below).
Since I cannot comment I can only ask here.

Here is the information provided.

**Hints.**

We first show that $2<\mathrm{e}<3$ (see below), and hence $\mathrm{e}$ is not an integer.

Next, following up OP's thought, assuming $\mathrm{e}=a/b$, we multiply by $b!$ and we obtain
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{b!}{k!}=a\cdot (b-1)! \tag{1}
$$
The right hand side of $(1)$ is an integer.

The left hand side of $(1)$ is of the form
$$
\sum_{k=0}^b \frac{b!}{k!}+\sum_{k=b+1}^\infty \frac{b!}{k!}= p+r.
$$
Note that $p=\sum_{k=0}^b \frac{b!}{k!}$ is an integer, while $$
0<r=\sum_{k=b+1}^\infty \frac{b!}{k!}=\frac{1}{b+1}+\frac{1}{(b+1)(b+2)}+\cdots<\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(b+1)^k}=\frac{1}{b}<1.
$$

**Note.** The fact that $\mathrm{e}\in (2,3)$ can be derived from the inequalities 
$$ 
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n}<\mathrm{e}<\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\!n+1},
$$
for $n=1$ for the left inequality and $n=5$ for the right inequality.

Comment: That's the usual "geometric series formula", is it not? Look up "summing a geometric series". Do you understand the rest of the proof?

Comment: **Hint :** Use sum of a infinte G.P to show that : $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac1{(b+1)^k} = \dfrac{\dfrac1{b+1}}{1 - \dfrac1{b+1}}$$

Comment: Russian guy .Yes I understand all. I think you are right it comes from 1+x+x^2+...n. I am terrible at pattern recognizing.

Comment: I feel stupid lol.

Comment: Where is this answer from?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch from e is irrational.Anyway I always feel dumb cannot think outside the box. How will I be a mathematician ;_;

Comment: @KarmaDhundup Cheer up! We all miss things sometimes

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit Why you guys are so fast at recognizing pattern ;_; why?????? I did several attempts and write till a page and got nowhere lol.

Comment: @KarmaDhundup Maybe ..... because of our *Karma* ?

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit lol I just turned to 17 does it sound young? I started at 16 studying real analysis what is your age?

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit May be you have more experience in Mathematics than me hehe. I am challenging myself to finish undergraduate course in math,physics,chemistry and CS at the age of 18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{∞}\frac{1}{\left(b+1\right)^{k}}=\frac{\frac{1}{\left(b+1\right)}}{1-\frac{1}{\left(b+1\right)}}=\frac{1}{b}<1$$

I used a well-known formula for geometric series, also since $b$ is a positive integer so $\frac{1}{b}$ , but if $b=1$ then $a/b=a$ is strickly between $2$ and $3$ which is a contra since $a$ is supposed to be an integer.

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3449983/proving-an-inequality-which-leads-to-the-proof-of-irrationality-of-frac1e) is a proof of mine which is about irrationaly of $1/e$ which is also useful for proving irrationaly of $e$.

Comment: Great thanks! I have my own alternative proof but same it does contradiction

Comment: you define the series of e as s_n then you define e as rational as lowest term a/b then get a a/b-(s_b=n/b!)=I/b! and we know l is interger since l/b! is lowest term then you get 0<(b+1)!^-1+(b+2)!...<(b!3)^-1+(b!3)^-2+...=0.5/q!<1 and because 0.5 it is contradiction sorry I am too busy to write it carefully. Hehe and I found in my question I was trapped I already had

Comment: done that kind of thinking in mind

Comment: since my brain is foggy now I need to play COD bye if you need serious proof I will give you if you are curious when need if I have time